# Connection between devices via blue tooth iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I am working on an `iOS Application` in which I want to list the bluetooth devices names and connect to any one of them and transfer data (messages).

Now I am using the `MultiPeerConnectivityFramework` which uses MCBrowserViewController for discovering nearby devices, but unfortunately i am not getting any device name in the MCBrowserViewController. Here is my code

```
-(void)setupPeerAndSessionWithDisplayName:(NSString *)_displayName{

self.peerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:_displayName];
self.session = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.peerID];
self.session.delegate = self;
```

}

-(void)setupMCBrowser{

```
self.browser = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat-files" session:self.session];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

MultipeerConnectivity is an Apple specific framework and does not work with Android devices, unfortunately.

To my knowledge, using Bluetooth for this type of cross platform connectivity is not possible. Especially not if you want to do it with apps not in the foreground.